# How to insert and delete value from Content MySQL field like 1,3,6

Tags: mysql, sql

i want insert a new value and delete a value from Content field

Example : the field Content like 1,3,6
i want insert on it 4 [+ old value] and delete only 6

the Value on a variable,

```
$var = '6';
```

if it present in the field will be deleted and if it do not exist will be added

CODE :

```
if (Condition)
{
// add new value + old value
UPDATE table_name
SET column=new value,old value
}else{
// delete only value 6 from filed 1,3,6
UPDATE table_name
SET column=value
}
```

Comment: you would be a lot better off making the changes to the input in your application and then passing in a clean data value to the SQL. Doing things like this in SQL is annoying and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot normalize (and it may not make sense to for your data set if all the values come from a small set), then you can convert your field to the SET type like this:

alter table tbl_name modify col_name set("1","2","3","4","5","6") not null;

the example assumes you have 6 possible unique values named "1" through "6".

Then to remove 6 you would do:

update tbl_name set col_name = col_name & ~32

to add 6 you would do

update tbl_name set col_name = col_name | 32

The general formula for the magic mask number (in this case 32) is 2^(n-1) where n is the position of the element in the set. For example, if we wanted to add/remove the fifth element of the set (in our case "5") the magic mask would become 2^(5-1) = 2^4 = 16

~ means bitwise NOT
& is bitwise AND
| is bitwise OR

The SET method works only if you have no more than 64 unique values. This is due to the limitation that they are internally stored as a 64-bit integer.